# How to open a list from python module depending upon user input

Tags: python

I have a bunch of lists in a module (say student_data) which I import in my file. All the list are of type student[1-100]. Now depending on user input I wish to iterate through the corresponding list. Lets say the user inputs 10 then I want to print the contents of list student10. How do I go about doing this?

```
Input in variable i
for x in student_data.student+i:
  print x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winston Ewert is definitely correct in what the *right* way to do this would be.

However, if you're locked into your existing data structure, what you want is to use the getattr function... this allows programmatic access to a specified attribute. In your case, `getattr(student_data, "student%d" % (i,))`

Comment: I'm always hesitant to tell people how to do stuff like that, I worry they'll abuse it.

Comment: That's certainly true, getattr is dangerously abusable. But I remember that (for me) learning about getattr helped me frame my concept of python objects and attribute access, that it wasn't some semantic thing you couldn't poke at very much (eg C struct access), but was a VM operation you could invoke yourself. I mainly posted it so that he would know how to properly communicate `student_data.student+i` in the correct form; even if learning to use it sparely only comes from painful experience :)

Answer (score 4):

You should put all of the lists into a big list of lists.

Then you use can the standard `student_data.student_lists[index]` to get an individual list.